# Constructing the Lebesgue Measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am studying for an exam and I am trying to work out a concise construction of the Lebesgue measure. Here is what I have:

If $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ with a premeasure $\mu_0:\mathcal{A}\to[0,\infty)$ where $\mu_0(A)$ is the length of $A\in\mathcal{A}$. Now we want to define the outer measure $\mu^*:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\to[0,\infty]$ such that if $E\subset\mathbb{R}$, take $E\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ for $A_i\in\mathcal{A}$ for all $i$ such that $\mu^*(E)=\inf\sum_i\mu_0(A_i)$. We can show then that $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$ and $\sigma$-additivity on $\mu^*$. Now, by Caratheodory, we have that $\mu^*$ is a complete measure in the $\sigma$-algebra of $\mu^*$ measurable sets, $\mathcal{M}$ (i.e. a set $K$ is $\mu^*$ measurable if $\mu^*(J)=\mu^*(J\cap K)+\mu^*(J\cap K^C)$ for all $J\subset\mathbb{R}$). But then $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{M}$ which means $\mu^*$ is the unique completion of $\mu_0$, so $\mathcal{M}=\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$. So, to give us what we want, we have a complete measure on $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ that defines the length of intervals. This means the measure is the Lebesgue measure. And there we have it.

The biggest questions I have about this:
1. I know I didn't define $\mathcal{A}$ very specifically, is that ok?
2. I am fairly confident in the beginning of the construction, I am a little more unsure on how to get the complete measure that I have established from Caratheodory to be the Lebesgue measure.
3. I didn't use $F(x)=x$, which really defines the Lebesgue measure. I think I just found a way around that, but is it not ok to leave that out?

Comment: For #1, by the topology axioms, the set of all sets which are open or closed is an algebra. At least in $\mathbb{R}$ it is the smallest algebra containing all open intervals. Thus if you want to extend your premeasure from this algebra, it should first be *defined* on this algebra. But the length of an interval is not well-defined on this entire algebra. So there is some work to be done to properly specify $\mu_0$.

Comment: For #2, you should establish some uniqueness, so that the Lebesgue measure is the only possible complete extension of the premeasure you started with. (This is not trivial; as I recall you need the space to be $\sigma$-finite to get this uniqueness.) For #3, it is built into the definition of the premeasure.

Comment: @Ian: The set of sets which are open or closed does **not** form an algebra, e.g. $(0,1) \cap [1/2, 2) = [1/2, 1)$ is neither open nor closed. The algebra in question here is (usually) just the set of all finite disjoint unions of intervals of the form $(a,b]$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Good catch. To me that raises an interesting question about construction of Borel measures (though I shouldn't distract from this post). Anyway, my main point in #1 was that you need to specify what $\mathcal{A}$ is and what $\mu_0$ is for all elements of $\mathcal{A}$, which allthatmath did not do in the original question.